# Testing security of untrusted image upload

Tags: security, upload, malware

I need to test how my website will deal with image files with malware embedded. I'm already satisfied with its validation of the file type using header inspection. I'm looking to test it with genuine image files with embedded malware.

Can I get a jpg that should be recognised as malware to test this? Or make one myself?

Or if there is a better way of doing it, how can I make sure that everything is wired up and working correctly?

It will be deployed on Azure with the images saved to Azure Blob storage. I want to use the [new] Azure storage security service to detect malware.

Comment: Are you able to provide details of the solution that you are using to detect the malware? Most vendors will be able to provide test files (i.e. files that will be treated as malicious but not have malicious content) that will allow you to do this.

Comment: @James Thanks for the info. I plan to use Azure Defender for Storage. It can generate an alert when malware is uploaded to the blob storage. I need to set up an automatic response to the alert that immediately deletes the blob in such a case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/defender-for-storage-introduction

Comment: This is likely to be a difficult one (unless the vendor is willing to share an image file). The obvious file that is used in a lot of testing is eciar (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file) The challenge here is it probably won't pass your test for being a valid image file.

Comment: @James Thank you, that's actually just what I was looking for. If I can't embed it in an image file then I can just check it with the image check turned off (not in production yet)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will add this as an answer for anyone else who comes across the question

Comment: For anyone looking into a similar approach, I found a delay between the upload and the security alert with Azure Defender of about an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typically difficult to use real malware for testing. You need to be able to handle the file in your test environment with care to not infect your systems, or, escape out into the rest of your network.

To facilitate testing anti-malware solutions vendors provide a number of test files. These are benign files which are detected as malicious. Therefore it is safe to use them in your environment but will serve as a good test case of your solution.

There is one industry standard file ([EICAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file)) which is available for testing anti-malware solutions. As you can see from [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/275a021bbfb6489e54d471899f7db9d1663fc695ec2fe2a2c4538aabf651fd0f/detection) almost every vendor will detect this file as malicious. Many of them identifying it as a test file.

In your particular use case there is one challenge here, it is not an image file. However, as you mention in the comments I believe that turning off the image detection during this test is much better than using real malware for testing.

Finally, one word of caution with EICAR. As so many products detect this as a virus you need to be careful of the anti-malware solution that is running on the systems that the file ends up on. For example, if your development environment contains an on access scanner attempting to run the test will potentially trigger the on access scanner.